# Odd Java Calendar behavior

Tags: java, calendar

Does anyone understand why is the year in the output 2077 instead of 2011?

```
Integer yyyyMMdd = 20110830
Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.DEFAULT);

Integer dd = yyyyMMdd % 100;
Integer yyyy = yyyyMMdd / 10000;

day.set(yyyy, MM-1, dd);

System.err.println(day.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Where does MM come from?  Also, try adding: Calendar.setLenient(false); after the second line and run it again.

Comment: And why are you using `Integer` instead of `int` everywhere? It won't be causing *problems* here, but it's distinctly odd.

Comment: Oh, and where is `TimeZone.DEFAULT` meant to come from? You're missing a semi-colon in the first line, too. If you're going to show a problem, please post real code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, WW. My variable "MM" has the wrong value which seems to be leaking over to "year".

Answer (score 5):

Having fixed up your code so that it actually compiles, I get the expected result - so presumably it's a bug in the code you were *really* running but hadn't shown. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int yyyyMMdd = 20110830;
        Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

        int dd = yyyyMMdd % 100;
        int MM = (yyyyMMdd % 10000) / 100;
        int yyyy = yyyyMMdd / 10000;

        day.set(yyyy, MM-1, dd);

        System.err.println(day.getTime());
    }
}
```

Result on my machine:

```
Tue Aug 30 07:18:33 BST 2011
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jon. You were right. My code was indeed rubbish